# Textarea with buttons like wordpress

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a PHP CMS for my website and i want to make buttons that do some code in the textarea, to be posted in my blog , when i click on bold for specific word it turn into bold and so on like wordpress theme or stackoverflow body , how can i achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: There are several plugins offering what you're looking for. Google for "javascript rich text editor".

Comment: This question is way too broad; you definitely need JavaScript for this, but suffice to say that even for a professional, creating an editor like this is a massive task.

Comment: @PedroLima thank you i found some tutorials about this on youtube :)

Comment: @ChrisG yes i tried creating buttons like this but its not working when i publish the post online .

Comment: What do the buttons do exactly? Do they insert bbcode or markdown into the textarea's text? Creating them does nothing, you need to implement click handlers.

Comment: @ChrisG i didn't know about this because i am still a junior developer , i am trying to learn more about javascript stuffs

Comment: What you can do for now is implement markdown; this means you need to format your posts like here on SO (i.e. with special characters instead of Word-style buttons) but it's easy to implement. All you need is a PHP markdown library, then run the stored post through it before inserting it into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CK editor](https://ckeditor.com/) or [Tiny](https://www.tiny.cloud/). These two are free to use.

Comment: Thank you for this , i was searching for a good one , and i guess Tiny is the perfect choice